# CSS process flow arrows - bad formatting?

Tags: html, css

[image]I modified 3 different peoples code to make css arrows and I think I made it more complicated than it needs to be.  Any CSS expert than can help me clean this up?
I can't seem to modify padding and other attributes to get this where I want it within the divs.

css

```
<style>
/* These are the Stage Arrows - styles */
#testStatus {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  left: 10px; 
}
.testStatus li {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  margin-left: -3px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: auto;
}
ul.testStatus {
  list-style: none;
  }
li.testStatus:first-child:after, li.testStatusGood:after, li.testStatusNoGood:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #767676;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    margin: -10px 0px 0px 10px; 
    z-index: 3;
}
li.testStatus:last-child:before, li.testStatusGood:before, li.testStatusNoGood:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    margin: -10px 0px 0px 0px; 
    z-index: 2;
}
li.testStatus:first-child {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #767676;
}
li.testStatus:last-child {
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #767676;
}
li.testStatusGood {
  background-color: #77a942; 
}
li.testStatusGood:after {
  border-left: 10px solid #77a942;
}
li.testStatusNoGood {
  background-color: #c42c00; 
}
li.testStatusNoGood:after {
  border-left: 10px solid #c42c00; 
}
/* End arrow formatting */
</style>
```

html

```
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="testStatus">
                    <ul class="testStatus">
                        <li class="testStatus">Step 1</li>
                        <li class="testStatusGood">Step 2</li>
                        <li class="testStatusNoGood">Step 3</li>
                        <li class="testStatusNoGood">Step 4</li>
                        <li class="testStatus">Step 5</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My arrows display nicely but I am having difficulty adjusting the padding to 0.  I've tried the #, the ul class, the il class and I am a bit baffled why I cannot remove the 10px (I believe its the padding).

There is also a faintly darker border on the left side of the triangular portion of the arrows, if you look closely, that I'd like to have match the color exactly.

[image]

Duo's code output above image, Ojer code output below image
[image]

I'm going backwards :)

Comment: can you edit the post with an image what you get with current styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  border: 1px solid #cbd2d9;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.breadcrumbs__item {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
}

.breadcrumbs__item:hover:after,
.breadcrumbs__item:hover {
  background: #edf1f5;
}

.breadcrumbs__item:focus:after,
.breadcrumbs__item:focus,
.breadcrumbs__item.is-active:focus {
  background: #323f4a;
  color: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbs__item:after,
.breadcrumbs__item:before {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, -50% -50%, 0 100%);
  content: "";
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
  width: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumbs__item:before {
  background: #cbd2d9;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.breadcrumbs__item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.breadcrumbs__item.is-active {
  background: #edf1f5;
}

/* Some styles to make the page look a little nicer */
body {
  color: #323f4a;
  background: #f5f7fa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


.gray{
background-color:gray;
}
.breadcrumbs__item.gray:after{
background-color:gray;
}

.red{
background-color:red;
}
.breadcrumbs__item.red:after{
background-color:red;
}


.green{
background-color:green;
}
.breadcrumbs__item.green:after{
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<li class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#Prospect" class="breadcrumbs__item gray">Prospect</a>
  <a href="#Opportunity" class="breadcrumbs__item red">Opportunity</a> 
  <a href="#Accound" class="breadcrumbs__item red">Accound</a>
  <a href="#Sales" class="breadcrumbs__item green">Sales</a> 
  <a href="#Support" class="breadcrumbs__item is-active">Support</a> 
</li>
```

Comment: Odd... I got no arrows but only text with hyperlinks.  Your code snippet works perfect.

Comment: do you have any other css code for this that may have .breadcrumbs  class in it?

Comment: I'm currently sandwiching your breadcrumbs inside of my original ul li classes.  But this doesn't solve my padding left alignment issue.

Comment: can you post you code after adding my code so i can look at that problem . is css applying now? is there's a padding problem you can inspect breadcrumbs and see which css class affecting it , after that you can either exclude breadcrumbs class from selector or add an override css where add `!important`  after css prosperities and put it in lowest portion of your code.

Comment: It is really the original problem.  I am just adding hyperlinks to my original code as you did in the Nav section.

Comment: here's a great article about creating breadcrumbs -> https://medium.com/design-code-repository/cutup-6-breadcrumb-bar-with-microdata-69de0d1ad00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243281/discussion-between-the-duo-and-vets).

Comment: Thank you for the assistance @The Duo. To keep the thread clean and on point, my padding issue was due to this div id="testStatus" which had CSS properties #testStatus of left: 10px.  That wasn't allowing me to get the arrows where I wanted them.  The code that The Duo provided is what I actually adopted and scrapped all my other code.  It was a bit sketchy.  Both work though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can work for you.

[Check this Pen](https://codepen.io/ojerdev/pen/qBpRWYG)

HTML:

```
<ul class="steps">
  <li class="past">
    <span>
      <strong>Step 1</strong>
    </span><i></i>
  </li>
  <li class="present">
    <span>
      <strong>Step 2</strong>
    </span><i></i>
  </li>
  <li class="future">
    <span>
      <strong>Step 3</strong>
    </span><i></i>
  </li>
  <li class="future1">
    <span>
      <strong>Step 4</strong>
    </span><i></i>
  </li>
  <li class="present1">
    <span>
      <strong>Step 5</strong>
    </span><i></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.steps {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.steps strong {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.1;
}

.steps > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /* border: 1px solid #ddd; */
  padding: 12px 50px 8px 50px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .steps > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .steps .past {
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
  }
  .steps .present {
    color: #000;
    background: yellow;
  }
  .steps .future {
    color: #fff;
    background: green;
  }
  .steps .present1 {
    color: #000;
    background: red;
  }
  .steps .future1 {
    color: #fff;
    background: purple;
  }
  .steps .present1 {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .steps li > span:after,
  .steps li > span:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-width: 30px;
  }

  .steps li > span:after {
    top: -4px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-width: 34px;
  }

  .steps li > span:before {
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .steps li.past + li > span:before {
    border-left-color: blue;
  }
  .steps li.present + li > span:before {
    border-left-color: yellow;
  }
  .steps li.future + li > span:before {
    border-left-color: green;
  }
  .steps li.future1 + li > span:before {
    border-left-color: purple;
  }

  .steps li:first-child > span:after,
  .steps li:first-child > span:before {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Arrows at start and end */
  .steps li:first-child i,
  .steps li:last-child i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-width: 30px;
  }

  .steps li:last-child i {
    left: auto;
    right: -30px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: @vets did you check the link I have provided in the answer?